# Cannot start child instances in Apache Karaf

Tags: apache-karaf

I may have a problem creating 'instances' in Apache Karaf 2.3.0.

```
karaf@root> admin:create FOO
...<some verbose lines on file copy activity>...
karaf@root> admin:list
```

This is what I got:

```
  SSH Port   RMI Ports         State       Pid  Name
[    8101] [1099/44444     ] [Started ] [ 5168] root
[    8107] [1105/44450     ] [Stopped ] [    0] FOO
karaf@root>
```

I tried `admin:start FOO` but nothing happens.
Karaf.log didn't indicate any errors.

Am I missing something? I was following 'Getting Started' guide on karaf.apache.org.
Could it be a bug?

Comment: Might be a bug, asking this on the users list of karaf is a better place though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the new instance

admin:start FOO

Cheers